# GUI in C language

Tags: c, user-interface

I am building a gui of multiple programs,  i want to combine them in one window by which the user could intially select which program to run. the window of the chosen program only appears. my question:  when i select one program the functions under this program don't work i.e:

switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

```
    case WM_CREATE:
        Main_createButton(hwnd);

    break;


    //____________________________________________________________________

    case WM_COMMAND:

        switch (LOWORD(wparam))
        {

            case Main_ID_RB_a:


                Q1_createButton(hwnd);
                Q1_picture(hwnd);
                Q1_Rad_But(hwnd);
                Q1_D_Price (hwnd);
                Q1_Comb_Box (hwnd);
                Q1_money_shwbox (hwnd);


               switch (Q1_Rad_But(hwnd))
        {
            case Q1_ID_BUTTON_FIRST:
                Q1_pressButton(hwnd);
            break;

            case Q1_ID_RB_a:

                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT1,"Apple Doughnut");
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT2,"5.30");
            break;
            case Q1_ID_RB_b:
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT1,"Cheese Doughnut");
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT2,"5.20");
            break;
            case Q1_ID_RB_c:
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT1,"Chocolate Doughnut");
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT2,"4.30");
            break;
            case Q1_ID_RB_d:
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT1,"Cruller Doughnut");
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT2,"4.50");
            break;
            case Q1_ID_RB_e:
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT1,"Glaze Doughnut");
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT2,"4.50");
            break;
            case Q1_ID_RB_f:
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT1,"Jelly Doughnut");
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT2,"4");
            break;
            case Q1_ID_RB_g:
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT1,"Muffin Doughnut");
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT2,"5");
            break;
            case Q1_ID_RB_h:
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT1,"Pumpkin Doughnut");
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT2,"3.30");
            break;
            case Q1_ID_RB_i:
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT1,"Strawberry Doughnut");
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT2,"4.70");
            break;
            case Q1_ID_RB_j:
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT1,"Sugar Doughnut");
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd,Q1_ID_EDIT_TEXT2,"3");
            break;



                //destroy Q2
                DestroyWindow(Q2S11);  DestroyWindow(Q2S12) ;DestroyWindow(Q2S13) ;DestroyWindow(Q2S14) ;DestroyWindow(Q2S15) ;
                DestroyWindow(Q2S16);  DestroyWindow(Q2S17);  DestroyWindow(Q2S18);  DestroyWindow(Q2S19);  DestroyWindow( Q2S110);
                DestroyWindow(Q2S111);  DestroyWindow(Q2S112);  DestroyWindow(Q2S113);  DestroyWindow(Q2S114);  DestroyWindow(Q2S115);
                DestroyWindow(Q2S116);  DestroyWindow(Q2S117);  DestroyWindow(Q2S118);  DestroyWindow(Q2S119);  DestroyWindow(Q2S120);
                DestroyWindow(Q2S121);  DestroyWindow(Q2S122);  DestroyWindow(Q2S123);  DestroyWindow(Q2S124);  DestroyWindow(Q2S125);

                DestroyWindow(Q2E11) ;DestroyWindow(Q2E12) ;DestroyWindow(Q2E13) ;DestroyWindow(Q2E14);DestroyWindow( Q2E15);
                DestroyWindow(Q2E16);  DestroyWindow(Q2E17);  DestroyWindow(Q2E18);  DestroyWindow(Q2E19); DestroyWindow(Q2E110);
                DestroyWindow(Q2E111);  DestroyWindow(Q2E112);

                DestroyWindow(Q2B1a);DestroyWindow(Q2B1b);DestroyWindow(Q2B1c);DestroyWindow(Q2B1d);DestroyWindow(Q2B1e);
                DestroyWindow(Q2B1f);DestroyWindow(Q2B1g);DestroyWindow(Q2B1h);DestroyWindow(Q2B1i);DestroyWindow(Q2B1j);
                DestroyWindow(Q2B1sel);

                DestroyWindow(Q2_staticText);DestroyWindow(Q2_staticText1);DestroyWindow(Q2_staticText2);DestroyWindow(Q2_staticText3);
                DestroyWindow(Q2_staticText4);DestroyWindow(Q2_staticText5);DestroyWindow(Q2_staticText6);DestroyWindow(Q2_staticText7);
                DestroyWindow(Q2_staticText8);DestroyWindow(Q2_staticText9);

                DestroyWindow(Q2_hBitmap);DestroyWindow(Q2_hBitmap1);DestroyWindow(Q2_hBitmap2);DestroyWindow(Q2_hBitmap3);
                DestroyWindow(Q2_hBitmap4);DestroyWindow(Q2_hBitmap5);DestroyWindow(Q2_hBitmap6);DestroyWindow(Q2_hBitmap7);
                DestroyWindow(Q2_hBitmap8);DestroyWindow(Q2_hBitmap9);

                DestroyWindow(Q2hComboBox);

                DestroyWindow(Q2B11);
                }


            break;
```

when  select one item  and the the program doesn't copy the name and value to edit text 1 and edit text two as shown 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD4Sk.png)[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Yes. You can have a button for each app, and only when pressed, the app will open

Comment: The code behind the button what i am asking about. Sure i have done like this regarding the button thing !

Comment: Show some [MCVE], so **edit your question** to improve it a lot. You need to add several more paragraphs, giving some context, some source code, telling about your widget library and environment.

Comment: done @BasileStarynkevitch

Answer (score 1):

Standard C99 or [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) does not know about GUIs and widgets. You can check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (which is basically the latest C standard specification).

So you'll be using some [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) library (probably running under some particular [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)). I recommend using [GTK](http://gtk.org/) (which is cross-platform).

You then could have your GTK program run other programs. Or you could (this is a bit harder) collect all the windows created by each code.

<sup>(in general, your question is very toolkit specific and has no obvious answer; it could even be [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) specific; in some cases, you could think of your program as behaving like some [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager))</sup>

Comment: Worth mentioning is the windows API for GUI development under windows OS.

Comment: I think it is much less portable than GTK. AFAIK that API only works on Windows.